# 42809 Error On Executing PostgreSQL Stored Procedure From Asp.Net C# Application

Tags: postgresql, procedure, npgsql

I am using PostgreSQL pgadmin4 (4.16v) with ASP.NET application. I have created a procedure as defined below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.usp_bind(
    )
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$
BEGIN
      select district_id,district_name from district_master order by district_name;
END;
$BODY$;
```

From asp.net application I have called above procedure, code as below:

```
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        public string dbconstr = dbConnectstr.Connectionstring();

        public DataSet getDatafunction(string procedure_, [Optional] string flag_)
        {
            using (conn = new NpgsqlConnection(dbconstr))
            {
                //conn.Open();
                using (da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter())
                {

                    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "CALL usp_bind";
                    da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;


                    using (ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds);
                    }
                }
                //conn.Close();
            }
            return ds;
        }
```

It's giving me an error as - **42809: 'usp_bind' is a procedure.**

I would have called it using a `CALL` method too but did't worked. What is the exact way to call a procedure from ASP.NET application?

Comment: Procedures are kind of new in PostgreSQL, so maybe Npgsql does not support it yet. Make sure you try with the latest version of Npgsql, and if that doesn't work either, look for Npgsql issues (I'm sure you are not the first on) or open a new one. Implementing Procedures in drivers like Npgsql or JDBC is kind of a challenge, because there used to be no procedures in PostgreSQL, so syntax like this traditionally was converted to a function call.

Comment: Procedures aren't meant to return anything. If you want to return something use a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't set `CommandType.StoredProcedure` on your command.

Unfortunately, stored procedures are new, and `CommandType.StoredProcedure` was already used to invoke *functions*, and changing that would be a major breaking change at this point.

Comment: my functions are working only by using `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: First, make sure you understand the difference between PostgreSQL stored *procedures* and *functions* - these are two different things (the former is called with `CALL`, the latter via `SELECT * FROM`). `CommandType.StoredProcedure` generates `SELECT * FROM`, so confusingly works only with functions; it also doesn't do anything you can't do yourself: you can just create a regular command without settings CommandType, and set the CommandText to `SELECT * FROM my_func(params...)`.