# How would I call a PostgreSQL 13 stored procedure from C#?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to call a PostgreSQL 13 Stored Procedure from C#.

- My first attempt below produced a **42809** error.
- After removing the `command.CommandType` assignment, I get a **42601** error.

  ```
       using (NpgsqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
        {
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("registerimport", connection);

            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("instid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, instrumentId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fname",  NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, fileInfo.Name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("createdstamp", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileInfo.CreationTime);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastaccessstamp", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileInfo.LastAccessTimeUtc);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastwritestamp", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fimportstamp", NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp, DateTime.UtcNow);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fsize", NpgsqlDbType.Bigint, fileInfo.Length);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("fhash", NpgsqlDbType.Text, fileHash);

            try {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally 
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                result = true;
            }
        }
  ```

The stored procedure is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.registerimport(
    instid integer,
    fname character varying,
    createdstamp timestamp without time zone,
    lastaccessstamp timestamp without time zone,
    lastwritestamp timestamp without time zone,
    fsize bigint,
    fimportstamp timestamp without time zone,
    fhash text)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
begin
        -- Insert the registration info into the ImportLog table.
        INSERT INTO importlog(
                instrumentid, 
                filename,
                creationtimeutc, 
                lastaccesstimeutc, 
                lastwritetimeutc, 
                filesize, 
                fileimportedutc, 
                filehash)
        VALUES (instId,
                fName,
                createdStamp,
                lastAccessStamp,
                lastWriteStamp,
                fSize,
                fImportStamp,
                fHash
               );
        COMMIT;
    end;
```

Is it possible to call a PostgreSQL 13 stored procedure from C#?

The next options that I will try are:

1. Convert all PostgreSQL 13 stored procedures to functions in the database.
2. Hard-code all SQL INSERT and UPDATE commands.

Comment: The code example you've provided is really old-school.  Using Dapper, it would simply be `var results = connection.Query(storedProcedureName, new { someParameters }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)`  See https://www.learndapper.com/stored-procedures

Comment: 42601 is a syntax error.  To diagnose that, we would have to see your stored procedure.

Comment: For the 42809 error, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60000410/102937

Comment: Yes, for the 42809 error, I removed the `command.CommandType` assignment after reading stackoverflow.com/q/60000410/102937.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the SQL for the stored procedure.

Comment: The SQL looks OK to me.  Did the error message give you any other information besides "Syntax Error"?

Comment: What is that COMMIT there for?  Doesn't that commit a transaction?  I don't see any declared transaction in your pgsql code.

Comment: The exception message is `42601: syntax error at or near "registerimport" POSITION: 1`.  Do I need the word `CALL` in front of the stored procedure name?  I will remove the COMMIT from the SQL.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232097/discussion-between-doug-kimzey-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Since the stored procedure is a straightforward `INSERT` command, I will write this in C# .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the correct syntax to invoke stored procedures is by using the `CALL` statement.

```
private void ExecuteProcedure(NpgsqlConnection connection) 
{
      using(var command = new NpgsqlCommand("CALL registerimport()", connection)) 
      {      
        //add all parameters
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("instid", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, instrumentId);
        //execute
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
}
```